# JDBC MySQL Connector/J Incorrect string value: '\xC3\xBCvifone...'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unicode, utf-8

I am having a trouble with inserting a valid UTF8 String into Percona MySQL database using `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8`. I use `jdk1.8.0_05`. This application is a console application.

I have the following String:  `Nüvifone G60`

I am trying to insert it to the database using `PreparedStatement`, using `setString` method.

My connection string is following:  `jdbc:mysql://host:post/schema?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

My `my.cnf` contains the following code:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

The table encoding where I am trying to insert the data is set to `utf8_general_ci`.

The error message I get is:
`java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC3\xBCvifo...' for column...`

Displaying the string to the console using `System.out.println` displays the String correctly.

I am playing it for entire day, and googled tens of sites with no result. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank your for everybody in advance.

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and confirm the `CHARACTER SET` for the *actual column* into which you are trying to insert the string. I can recreate your issue if I define a column as `varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii` in a table (and database) which is otherwise completely utf8. If necessary, please edit your question and post the results of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Gord, you have found the problem. For some reason, in table with about 15 columns, this only one column had ascii charset set, while all the other columns were correctly set to utf8. For some reason I had to miss it. Thank you a lot, you have saved me a lot of time! How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like that one particular column is unable to accept UTF-8 characters.

Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and confirm the `CHARACTER SET` for the *actual column* into which you are trying to insert the string. I can recreate your issue if I define a column as `varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii` in a table (and database) which is otherwise completely utf8.

Answer (score 1):

`PreparedStatement` has a `setCharacterStream()` method which take a `Reader` object.

Now you could use a `StringReader` to read your string value into the database through `setCharacterStream()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however, the problem was different (check Gord Thompson comment). Thanks anyway!